# Episerver 7 upgraded from 6, move page types to code

Tags: c#, migration, episerver, episerver-7

I have a project which is just upgraded from EpiServer 6 to 7. Project is running fine, but now I would like to move the pagetypes into classes deriving from PageData. How would I proceed doing this? We do not have PageTypeBuilder defined types, all is from database. I guess we start with the GUID from the page type in admin gui and set it in ContentType attribute of the PageData class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Alf's re-work of Erik's tool here:

http://talk.alfnilsson.se/2013/03/08/creating-page-type-classes-from-page-types-in-episerver-cms-7/

Download here:

https://github.com/alfnilsson/pagetypeclasses